# Beamer columns with multiple same slides

Tags: beamer, columns

In beamer, I come across a little problem with the columns environment. In one slide, I always put picture on the left and text on the right. The problem is, when this slide is shown at first, the picture shows twice, i.e. two same slide. Then the text is shown fine. 
I understand this is not a big issue, but I am wondering is there any solution to get rid of the first one? In other words, when the slide is shown, left column appears and then right column..., not left column appears TWICE.

Apologies for my bad English. Here is a MWE:

```
%% Test columns
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
        A figure
    \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
        \end{itemize}
      \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The code above has only one slide within one frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\uncover<>{}` to specify on which slides its contents will be shown. In you case, one for the first slide and other for the second.

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame}
\begin{columns}
\uncover<1>{%
   \column{.5\textwidth}A figure
}
\uncover<2>{%
   \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
        \end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

If you want to show the first slide and after keep it and show the second, then use `\uncover<1,2>` **instead** of `\uncover<1>`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. It works fine for me. There is another problem about this. I put this MWE in a single document and it works perfectly. However, the exact same code in my long presentation document would appear weird. The first slide is deleted for sure, but the right column is appear as "ready mode" (i.e. virtual text to be ready to shown). I don't know if there is any package collision or something. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Shea, sorry. I don't understand you. What do you mean by *virtual text*? Are you talking about the transparency of the hidden text that will be shown on next step? Also what do you mean by *The first slide is deleted for sure*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes I mean the transparency. The first slide (repetitive) is not there after using the \uncover<1,2> command.

Comment: So, the place for it is reserved but it does not appear on both #1,#2 slides? Please, post here the line where you define the amount of transparency.